# Using ant, find files matching a regular expression and search if a substring in present in the file

Tags: ant

I have a directory containing 2 files:

abc_2010-14-12.log

abcdef.log

I want to search for a substring in the 1st file. But i dont know the exact file name as it has timestamp appended to it. I think i will have to use regular expression in the file name.

Answer (score 8):

First you must identify the file.  You may be able to do that using a normal `fileset` include:

```
<fileset dir="." id="the.file" includes="abc_????-??-??.log" />
```

If that might give you a false positive on something like 'abc_XXXX-YY-ZZ.log', then you can use a [`filename`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Types/selectors.html#filenameselect) selector, which has more powerful matching than the 'glob' wildcarding available in include and exclude rules:

```
<fileset dir="." id="the.file">
    <filename regex=".*_[0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9]-[0-9][0-9].log"/>
</fileset>
```

You might be able to restrict further, assuming (based on your example) YYYY-DD-MM:

```
<filename regex=".*_20[01][0-9]-[0-3][0-9]-[01][0-9].log"/>
```

These will give you a fileset that matches, hopefully just the one file.

If you have more than one matching file present - say several days' log files - you'll need to decide which one you want.  You could make use of the [`tstamp`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/tstamp.html) task to exactly specify the filename based on the current date, rather than using a pattern match or glob.  This example gets the file with yesterday's date, matching your format:

```
<tstamp>
    <format property="file.date" pattern="yyyy-dd-MM"
            offset="-1" unit="day"/>
</tstamp>
<fileset dir="." id="the.file" includes="abc_${file.date}.log" />
```

Once you have identified the file, you can use the [`resourcecontains`](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/conditions.html) condition to set a property if the file matches - in this case we search for 'look for me':

```
<condition property="file.matches">
    <resourcecontains refid="the.file" substring="look for me" />
</condition>
```

Comment: In ant 1.8.2 I get an error using fileset as resource java.lang.ClassCastException: org.apache.tools.ant.types.FileSet cannot be cast to org.apache.tools.ant.types.Resource

Comment: Are the regex expressions in Ant Perl compatible?

Comment: How can I search pattern using regex in each file?