# How do I append a line to a file unzipped by Ant?

Tags: java, ant, log4j

I have a default `log4j` properties file to which I want to append an application specific configuration. The file is contained (with other files) within a .zip file. I use Ant to unzip the contents of the zip (including the log4j properties). I want to append the line when the unzip happens. Is this possible?

```
<unzip dest="some.dest">
    <fileset refid="some.fileset" />
    <!-- Append a line to 'log4j.properties` file -->
</unzip>
```

Maybe the solution is just to echo after I've unzipped.

Comment: Don't know a straight way with vanilla ant, but no need to fiddle with unzipping the whole archive .. etc., dealing with log4j.properties is sufficient, see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Ant "echo" task with the "append" flag:

```
<echo file="log4j.properties" append="true">${line.separator}</echo>
```

Echo task doc here for further reference:

http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/echo.html

Comment: Unzip doesn't support nested echo element.

Comment: My assumption was that you could place it following the "unzip" task within the same target, instead of nested. Is there a reason that you need it to be nested?

Comment: Not really, if you know the contents of the zip file. If the zip has some weird folder structure, you might not know the full unzipped folder path of the properties file. So if you could append inside the unzip, it would know where to put it correctly.

Comment: Given that, my approach would be to use a "fileset" task after the "unzip" task, to search for the desired files to modify. This question has the starting point for that approach: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4436727/using-ant-find-files-matching-a-regular-expression-and-search-if-a-substring-in

Answer (score 0):

No need to unzip the whole zipfile, use

if log4j.properties resides in rootdirectory of zip :

```
<project>
  <!-- unzip log4j.properties only -->
  <unzip src="foo.zip" dest=".">
    <patternset>
      <include name="log4j.properties" />
    </patternset>
  </unzip>
  <!-- put new key in or overwrite if already existing -->
  <propertyfile file="log4j.properties">
    <entry key="log4j.logger.com.foobar.xyz" value="ERROR" />
  </propertyfile>
  <!-- update zip with modified log4j.properties -->
  <zip destfile="foo.zip" update="true">
    <fileset dir="." includes="log4j.properties" />
  </zip>
</project>
```

else if log4j.properties resides in any subfolder of zip :

```
<project>
  <!-- unzip log4j.properties only -->
  <unzip src="foo.zip" dest=".">
    <patternset>
      <include name="**/log4j.properties" />
    </patternset>
  </unzip>
  <fileset dir="." includes="**/log4j.properties" id="foo"/>
  <!-- put new key in or overwrite if already existing -->
  <propertyfile file="${toString:foo}">
    <entry key="log4j.logger.com.foobar.xyz" value="ERROR" />
  </propertyfile>
  <!-- update zip with modified log4j.properties -->
  <zip destfile="foo.zip" update="true">
    <fileset dir="." includes="${toString:foo}" />
  </zip>
</project>
```

Comment: I actually do need to unzip all files.